# Debug embedded tomcat on heroku

Tags: java, debugging, tomcat, heroku

I'm working on a Java web application. I already deploy it to heroku. Now I'm trying to remote debug my application using IntelliJ with no results. To deploy it I use git, then heroku starts it reading and executing the Procfile. And here is the problem. Everywhere I see that to debug I must use this line in my Procfile: `web: java -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,address=9090,suspend=n -jar target/myapp.jar`. But I can't put this line on my Procfile because I execute my app using `web: sh target/bin/webapp` and not java. There's some workaround to simply debug my application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need [Heroku Exec and the Heroku Java CLI](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/exec#using-java-debugging-tools).

First, put your `agentlib` args into the `JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS` env var:

```
$ heroku config:set JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS="-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,address=9090,suspend=n"
```

This way, the `java` process in your `target/bin/webapp` script will pick it up automatically.

Then run:

```
$ heroku ps:forward 9090
```

And you can connect to `localhost:9090` from your IDE.